# Show a div if ng-repeat with a ng-if returns null

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to show a div with some message in it when the ng-repeat returns null. My ng-repeat is accompanied by an ng-if for simple filtering the json.

**Here is my HTML**

```
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-remove-animate" ng-repeat="uit in useritems" 
      ng-if="uit.catid == categoryI" type="item-text-wrap" >
        <h2>{{uit.user}}</h2>
        <p>{{uit.pass}}</p>
        <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="remove(uit.uniqueid)">
          Delete
        </ion-option-button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <!-- DIV to show message -->
    <div class="someclass">
      SOME MSG
    </div>
    <!-- DIV to show message -->
```

Comment: What do you mean ng-repeat returns null ?

Comment: your means is if `useritems` is `null`?

Comment: My useritems is not null.  I'm showing the useritems with an ng-if. Sometimes that filtering result is empty(not useritems). I wanna show that div on that condition.

Comment: @Dino: Check my answer below, I hope that is what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend you to use a custom `directive`.

```
<ion-item class="item-remove-animate" ng-repeat="uit in useritemsFiltered = (useritems | filter:customFilter)"  type="item-text-wrap" >
    <h2>{{uit.user}}</h2>
    <p>{{uit.pass}}</p>
    <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="remove(uit.uniqueid)">
      Delete
    </ion-option-button>
</ion-item>
```

Your directive should look like this:

```
var someApp=angular.module('someApp', []);
someApp.filter('customFilter', function() {
      return function(input, uppercase) {
         var out = [];
         for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
          if(input[i].catid == categoryI){
              out.push(input[i]);
          }
        }
        return out;
      }
});
```

```
<div class="someclass" ng-show="!useritemsFiltered.length">
   SOME MSG
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `alias` to the actual array in the ng-repeat and show the div based on its length as shown below :

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item class="item-remove-animate" ng-repeat="uit in useritems as filtered" 
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The `filtered` array has only filtered items based on the actual `useritems`, Hence you can show the below `div` when it's length is equal to zero.

```
<!-- DIV to show message -->
<div class="someclass" ng-show="!filtered.length">
  SOME MSG
</div>
<!-- DIV to show message -->
```

Just for clear understanding, here is the explanation about the `alias_expression` from angular documentaion :

> variable in expression as alias_expression – You can also provide an
>   optional alias expression which will then store the intermediate
>   results of the repeater after the filters have been applied. Typically
>   this is used to render a special message when a filter is active on
>   the repeater, but the filtered result set is empty.
>
> `For example: item in items | filter:x` as results will store the
>   fragment of the repeated items as results, but only after the items
>   have been processed through the filter.